# Laravel 5.3 and Zizaco/entrust : Field 'expired_at' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I am using composer `Zizaco/entrust` and Laravel `5.3`'s `Auth` out of the box,

I modified the method `create` of `RegisterController.php` like this:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user =User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    $user->roles()->attach($data['role']);
    return $user;
}
```

The original method `create` is as follow:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

When I register an user with the modified method,there are 2 problems:

1、There is an  error on table `role_user`:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'expired_at' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `role_user` (`role_id`, `user_id`) values (2, 5))
```

2、Another question is on table `users`,the field `remember_token` of table `users` is null.

Comment: _expired_at_ doesn't have a default value so you need to set it yourself when assigning a new role.

Answer (score 2):

It's not at the `users` table. its on `role_user` table.

If you have the migration on `role_user` put `nullable` on `expired_at` column should solve it.

Or

You can edit your `database.php` under config folder. and set `strict` to `false`.

For question number 2:
You need to set remember when attempt:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
     // The user is being remembered...
}
```

for more information about it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#remembering-users

By default `remember_token` is nullable

Comment: question  1 is on `role_user`,and question  2 is on `users`.

Comment: Question 1 is ok,Thanks! On question 2,what should I do?

Comment: Add `$table->string('remember_token', 100)->nullable();` in `users` table for Question:2.